# Finding comma separated String values in a List<int>

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a comma separated string variable and i need to check its values exists in a given List

```
string freeServices = "1,7,13,21";
List<int> selectedServices = booking.SelectedServices.Select(x => x.ServiceID).ToList();
```

i have tried something like this

```
if (selectedServices.Contains(Convert.Int32(freeServices.Split(','))
{
}
```

can i do this? or is there any other easy way to find whether the free service ids in selected id list?

Comment: A simple loop-inside-a-loop may seem inefficient, but it's what all that fancy Linq stuff does internally anyway, you know. Seems people forget that sometimes, you just need to program stuff yourself instead of relying on fancy tricks.

Answer (score 1):

To check, all values are contained in `SelectedServices`:

```
string freeServices = "1,7,13,21";
var values = freeServices.Split(',').Select(o=>Convert.ToInt32(o)).ToList();

List<int> selectedServices = booking.SelectedServices.Select(x => x.ServiceID).ToList();

if (selectedServices.All(o=>values.Contains(o))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query, you willget contains records

```
var containsValues = booking.SelectedServices.where(e=> freeServices.Split(',').Contains(e.ServiceID));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `All` and `int.Parse`;

```
string freeServices = "1,7,13,21";
List<int> selectedServices = booking.SelectedServices.Select(x => x.ServiceID).ToList();
var splittedFreeServices = freeServices.Split(',').Select(k => int.Parse(k));
var result = selectedServices.All(x => splittedFreeServices.Contains(x));
if (result) //booking.SelectedServices contains all elements of freeServices as integer
{

}
```

Comment: You will do `freeServices.Split(',')` for every item in `selectedServices`